# How to detect when user focuses Edit Text and place cursor on the right (end)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

I'm having a hard time with the EditText widget. It automatically focuses when the application starts and it does not unfocus when I'm done editing. I can't seem to understand how to capture the following events: opening the virtual keyboard, closing/hiding the virtual keyboard.

**What happens:** When the user touches an EditText widget, the virtual keyboard opens up and the cursor is placed in the position where the user touched.

**What I want to change:** I want the cursor to appear on the right (at the end of the text) when the user interacts with the Edit Text (ie, opens up the virtual keyboard) no matter where they touched. Each time the user opens up the virtual keyboard to interact with that specific EditText, I want the cursor to start on the right to make it easier to edit. After that, the user can edit normally and move the cursor anywhere as usual. Then I need the widget to get unfocused when editing is done, so that this behaviour can be repeated the next time the user edits.

For now I'm testing how to achieve that in a separate testing app. I made a very basic application with just a Linear Layout and the Edit Text widget based on other answers I encountered but unfortunately couldn't solve my problem. Here's what it looks like:

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="65336"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainLayout);
    EditText editor = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);

    editor.EditorAction += (sender, args) => {
        if (args.ActionId == Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done) {
            editor.ClearFocus();
            linear.RequestFocus();
            Toast.MakeText(this, "IME Done", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    };

    editor.FocusChange += (sender, args) => {
        if (args.HasFocus)
        {
            editor.SetSelection(editor.Text.Length);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Focusing", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Unfocusing", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    };
}
```

And I have no idea what's going on. What happens right now is when I touch the EditText widget, I get the "Focusing" Toast but the cursor is no set to the end. The cursor will be set to the end *if the EditText was focused automatically when starting the app* which I was trying to avoid by enabling, on the Linear Layout, the properties `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode` and set `descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`.

So then the IME keyboard shows. If I click the UI arrow to close the keyboard nothing happens. If I click the "Done" virtual key, I get the "IME Done" Toast. The EditText does get unfocused, but the virtual keyboard remains. Actually, my EditText has a "number" `input type` and the keyboard turns into a regular text keyboard instead.

If I remove the `linear.RequestFocus` line, then when I click "Done" on the virtual keyboard the EditText will automatically get re-focused and the keyboard does not vanish until I manually hide it. The EditText widget stays focused the entire time. I can't even find how to detect the "virtual keyboard hiding" event.

I've also tried adding an event handler to `Click`, but then the cursor is moved whenever I click the text, focused or not.

I'm just trying to understand what is the right event handler to use here but I can't understand the behaviour in this example at all, let alone figure out what I'm trying to achieve. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try setting android:gravity="right".

Comment: @Abhi That only aligns the text to the right. It's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the cursor at the end, please follow this solution:

```
final int numberOfItems = Integer.parseInt(yourEditText.getText().toString());
final int length = Integer.toString(numberOfItems).length();


        /* Move to last cursor in edit text */
        yourEditText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourEditText.setSelection(length);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, you might've skipped the code section in my question but I'm already doing that: `editor.SetSelection(editor.Text.Length);`. Thanks though.